# First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Invalid entity type for whatId

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, process-builder, salesforce-id

Getting Following error in the below code 
`23:27:13:030 FATAL_ERROR System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Invalid entity type for whatId.: [whatId, a09R000000AAPh5]`

When i Print the `InvoiceId` 18 Char is printed but while sending in `setWhatId` 15 Char is sent.( Not sure this could be the Problem).

If i hard coded the 18 Char value in `setWhatId` it's working.

Can anyone help me on this this?

```
global class InvoiceDueNotification implements Database.batchable<sObject>{


global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    String query = 'Select Id, Due_Date__c, Billing_Period_Name__c, Program_Name__c, Student_Family_Account__c, Student__c, Name, Amount__c, OwnerId from Invoice__c where Status__c =\'Open\'' ;
    system.debug('query' + query);
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,  List<Invoice__c> scope)
{

    for(Invoice__c inv :(List<Invoice__c>) scope){
        Integer numberDaysDue = inv.Due_Date__c.daysBetween(Date.today());            
        system.debug('numberDaysDue' + numberDaysDue);
        If (numberDaysDue >= 5){
            Id TemplateId = NULL;
            TemplateId = [SELECT Id,Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =: 'Payment_Reminder'].Id;
            Account acc  = [SELECT Family_Emails__c,Name from Account where id=:inv.Student_Family_Account__c];
            string InvoiceId =  inv.Id;
            //send email
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            email.setTemplateId(TemplateId);         
            system.debug('inv' + InvoiceId);
            email.setTargetObjectId('003R000001QLot4IAD');
            email.setWhatId(InvoiceId); 
            email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
            string[] to = new string[] {'test89@gmail.com'};  
            email.setToAddresses(to);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});


        } 
    }

}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
}

}
```

Comment: email.setWhatId((Id) InvoiceId); Not Working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activities are not enabled for the Invoice object. Go to the Object Manager, and edit the properties of the object to allow activities.

Alternatively, use `mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);` so that no Tak is created.

As a side note, you need to create a list of emails, and send then atl at once, or you may reach governor limits.

Also, if you change your query, you can get rid of the if statement, and drastically improve your batch performance.